# Conversion between two stream types

Tags: haskell, type-conversion, isomorphism

I have a question regarding converting between two datatypes in Haskell.

> Consider the following two datatypes
>
> ```
> data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)
>
> data Stream2 a = ST {shead :: a, stail :: Stream2 a}
> ```
>
> Q2: Write
>
> ```
> sToS2 :: Stream a -> Stream2 a
>
> s2ToS :: Stream2 a -> Stream a
> ```
>
> that convert between the two representations of streams

The first thing that I am having trouble with is the Stream datatype, We can see this is a recursive datatype but there is no base case, which makes me wonder if this is somehow infinite and how I could go about creating a stream datatype. Furthermore the constructor for Stream2 is given in record syntax where one of the fields is also something of type Stream2. I understand there was a question similar to time where

```
data Ab = A | B
data Cd = C | D

fromAb :: Ab -> Cd
fromAb A = C
fromAb B = D

toAb :: Cd -> Ab
toAb C = A
toAb D = B
```

but I am unsure how I can apply the answers from this question to my particular confusion.

Answer (score 6):

> there is no base case, which makes me wonder if this is somehow infinite

It is!

> and how I could go about creating a stream

Recursively! Haskell is nonstrict, so this is no problem. Behold:

```
successors :: Num a => a -> Stream a
successors start = Cons start $ successors $ start + 1

λ> case successors 1 of Cons _ (Cons _ (Cons x _)) -> x
3
```

> the constructor for Stream2 is given in record syntax where one of the fields is also something of type Stream2

Indeed. Aside from using the record sugar, the `Stream2` type is identical (or, more precisely, *isomorphic*) to `Stream`. We might line things up a bit to make the parallels more visually obvious:

```
data Stream  a = Cons            a           (Stream  a)
data Stream2 a = ST   { shead :: a, stail ::  Stream2 a }
--   [  1  ]     [ 2 ]          [3]           [   4   ]
```

1. The type
2. The type's only constructor
3. Type of the first constructor parameter
4. Type of the second constructor parameter

You can ignore the record syntax when you're writing the conversions.

```
sToS2 :: Stream  a -> Stream2 a
s2ToS :: Stream2 a -> Stream  a

sToS2 (Cons x xs) = ST   x $ sToS2 xs
s2ToS (ST   x xs) = Cons x $ s2ToS xs
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am trying to give implementation for the two functions
 sToS2 :: Stream a -> Stream2 a
 s2ToS :: Stream2 a -> Stream a

Where it converts between the two data types.

Comment: @Maxtwelve I know, this answer is a work in progess. See the latest edit.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Can the Cons operator be used for data type that is not a list? Can it just be read the same way as in x is the head and xs is the tail of the Stream datatype?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.